# Stein-Shakarchi Real Analysis Ch1 Ex5(b): Counterexample for approximation of bounded open sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The following is an exercise from *Real Analysis* by Stein-Shakarchi:

> [image]

The setting here is ${\bf R}^d$ with the Lebesgue measure. (a) can be proved by the monotonicity of the Lebesgue measure. The closed and unbounded counterexample for (b) could be ${\bf Z}$ in ${\bf R}$.

I have difficulties in the last question: how can I find a counterexample for the open bounded case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, and define
$$ E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(r_n-\frac{1}{4^n},r_n+\frac{1}{4^n}\Big) $$
Then $E$ is open and bounded, with
$$ m(E)\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}4^{-n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{2}{3} $$

However, if $x\in [0,1]$ then $d(x,E)=0$ since $E$ contains $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Therefore $\mathcal{O}_n$ contains $[0,1]$ for all $n$, so $m(\mathcal{O}_n)\geq 1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=\cup_{m\in \mathbb N}\;(3m-2^{-m},\;3m+2^{-m}).$

Then $O_n=\cup F_n$ where $F_n=\{\;(3m-2^{-m}-1/n,\;3m+2^{-m}+1/n)\;:m\in \mathbb N\}.$

The members of $F_n$ are pairwise-disjoint for $n\in \mathbb N$, and $m(f)>2/n$ for each $f\in F_n.$ So $m(O_n)=\infty$ but $m(E)=2.$